# how to make a query text and run it in cursor.execute

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to frame an oracle query text and then feed that query in to the cursor.execute function program.  It's not working as expected. I am able to print the correct query text, but unable to execute it in `cursor.execute`.

```
      # import modules
        import cx_Oracle

        # database connection
        user=input('Enter the user for database : ')
        passwd=input('enter the password for the above user : ')
        conn_str=user+'/'+passwd+'@localhost/orcl'
        conn=cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)

        # creation of cursor
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cur=cursor.execute('select distinct emp_name from employee')

        employee=[]

        for i in cur:
            print(i[0])
            employee.append(i[0])

        print(employee)

        cur=cursor.execute('select distinct month_name from employee')
        months=[]

        for i in cur:
            print(i[0])
            months.append(i[0])

        print(months)

        for i in employee:
            for j in months:
                query=str('select salary from employee where emp_name=\''+i[0]+'\' and month_name = \''+j[0:3]+'\'')
                print(query)
                cur=cursor.execute(query)
                print(cur)

        #closing cursor and connection
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: unexpected output:

select salary from employee where emp_name='e' and month_name = 'jan'
<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to system@localhost/orcl>>

Comment: Thanks! in the above case I am stuck at the point to create a query text. Once I get some help in this issue... I would be able to code the solution in python. Let me know if you can help me with some guidance.

Comment: (i) you should try to do this in one single SQL statement.  If you need help with this, go to asktom.oracle.com (ii) if you persist with an (inefficient) multi statement solution then you MUST use bind variables for performance and security.  Check the cx_Oracle documentation https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html  Also refer to all the cx_Oracle examples https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples